# Why does the nib have to be loaded for the headerView in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

```
-(UIView*) headerView{
    if(!headerView){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"HeaderView" owner:self options: nil];
    }
    return headerView;
}
```

In the `xib` file, i made a `pointer` from the file's owner to the `headerView`. Why is this not enough, and the `Nib` needing to be loaded?

Comment: To the editor of the question: The back ticks are for **code**. Marking all keywords such as `xib`, `pointer`, `Nib` as code does not (in my opinion) increase the readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection from the view to the `headerView` property of the file's owner has only
the effect that *when* the nib is loaded (with `owner:self`) *then* `self.headerView` is set
to that view.

The connection in the xib file does not have any effect before the nib is loaded.

Comment: In UIViewControllers, is this loading of the Nib done automatically when loadView is called? given that we have not overridden anything?

Comment: @ByronS: See the `loadView` documentation: *"If the view controller has an associated nib file, this method loads the view from the nib file. ..."* So yes, for view controllers from storyboard or nib files, this works automatically.